# Best way to store the configuration values/settings in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Since there is no default configuration file In a WP8 app, what is the best way to store the configuration values, e.g. WCF service URL, User Name and Password. I want these values to be available and updatable when phone restarts and app is closed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`.

**Save a value:**

```
IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
appSettings.Add("email", "someone@contoso.com");
appSettings.Save();
```

**Load a value:**

```
IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
string val = (string)appSettings["email"];
```

See the MSDN tutorial here: [How to: Store and Retrieve Application Settings Using Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). It is a desktop Silverlight tutorial but it works the same way in Windows Phone.

**EDIT:**

Using `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` can be problematic if your app uses background agents (**thanks @RichardSzalay for the info**).

If your agent only reads, `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` with a Mutex is recommended.

Source: [Background agent best practices for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have *any* kind of background agent, it's strongly advised that you *don't* use `IsolatedStorageSettings`

Comment: I'm using simple toast notification using periodic task of background agent. Is this will be a issue. Kindly guide .

Comment: @Kathir - From the docs: "We recommend that you do not use IsolatedStorageSettings to communicate between processes because it is possible for the data to become corrupt". If your background agent needs to access it, use your own (isolated storage backed) persistance.

Comment: I am using Background agent with Mutex only. So shall i use IsolatedStorageSettings.
Sorry if my question is worse.

Comment: If your background agent only reads the application settings, then you can use IsolatedStorageSettings (with a Mutex).

Comment: Kindly explain briefly on '(isolated storage backed) persistance'.
Do you mean that we need to use SQLLite or some other?

Comment: No, you don't need SQLLite for storing application settings, except if settings need to changed in the background agent. Please re-read my edited answer and the 'Background agent best practices for Windows Phone' page.

Comment: In my app settings are read for Background Agent but not editable.
From the docs:'For one-direction communication where the foreground app writes and the agent only reads, we recommend using an isolated storage file with a Mutex.'. Here i struct to move on?

Comment: Here is some sample code to get you started: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7ScheduledTaskAgent-6450bcf1

Comment: Basically, IsolatedStorageSettings are loaded only once into a static field. There is no way to reload them :(

Answer (score 0):

I searched for many solutions, I found this one the best:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510(v=vs.92).aspx

Cheers