# Save Permanently File in local data on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to make setting in my app that it just use for 2 time. I want to save some data (How much time that used) But when reinstalling app, I can access that data.
When we delete app, so data deleted.
How can do it, please?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to store the configuration values/settings in Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723166/best-way-to-store-the-configuration-values-settings-in-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to take a look at the [Local Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx)